# Why am I obtaining this error trying to perform the insert of a record using Spring Data JPA? Table 'db_test.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am very new in Spring Data JPA and I have the following problem trying to insert a record into a database table (I am using MariaDB) in a Spring Boot application.

This is my database table named **customer_order**:

```
'id',              'bigint(20)',   'NO', 'PRI', NULL,   'auto_increment'
'name',            'varchar(255)', 'NO', '',    NULL,   ''
'address',         'varchar(255)', 'NO', '',    NULL,   ''
'product',         'varchar(255)', 'NO', '',    NULL,   ''
'order_date_time', 'datetime',     'NO', '',    NULL,   ''
'quantity',        'tinyint(4)',   'NO', '',    NULL,   ''
```

This table is mapped with the **CustomerOrder** model class in my application:

```
@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
@Table(name = "customer_order")
public class CustomerOrder {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String fullName;
    private String address;
    private String product;

    @Column(name = "order_date_time")
    private String orderDate;

    private int quantity;

    public CustomerOrder() {
        super();
    }

    public CustomerOrder(String fullName, String address, String product, String orderDate, int quantity) {
        super();
        //this.id = id;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.address = address;
        this.product = product;
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public String getOrderDate() {
        return orderDate;
    }

    public void setOrderDate(String orderDate) {
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomerOrder [id=" + id + ", fullName=" + fullName + ", address=" + address + ", product=" + product
                + ", orderDate=" + orderDate + ", quantity=" + quantity + "]";
    }


}
```

I have this Spring Data JPA repository interface:

```
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<CustomerOrder, Integer> {

}
```

This is used by this service class to perfrom the database interaction:

```
@Service
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {

    @Autowired
    OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Override
    public List<CustomerOrder> getOrdersList() {
        List<CustomerOrder> result = (List<CustomerOrder>) orderRepository.findAll();
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public void insertOrder(CustomerOrder order) {
        orderRepository.save(order);
    }


}
```

Finnally I have this test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { Application.class })
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = { "no-liquibase" })
public class ExcelResourceIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    OrderServiceImpl orderService;

    @Test
    public void insertOrderServiceTest() {
        CustomerOrder testOrder =  new CustomerOrder("TEST1", 
                                                     "Test Street 35 - New York - USA", 
                                                     "TEST PRODUCT 1", "2020-03-24 12:10:00", 
                                                     3);
        orderService.insertOrder(testOrder);

    }

    @Test
    public void getOrdersListServiceTest() {    
        List<CustomerOrder> ordersList = orderService.getOrdersList();

        assertThat(ordersList).isNotEmpty();
    }

}
```

The problem is that performing the previous **insertOrderServiceTest()** it enters into the called service method but when this line is executed:

```
orderRepository.save(order);
```

I obtain the following error message into the console:

```
2020-03-24 04:20:56.915  INFO 4843 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@24e7087a, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@3a45308f, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@731fae, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@52bc6fcf, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@64b8eb96, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@789d8fd6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@5bb3dee7, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@4ae6451d, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@58ad0586, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@1e36baca]
2020-03-24 04:20:57.670  INFO 4843 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-03-24 04:20:58.368  INFO 4843 --- [           main] c.s.e.i.ExcelResourceIntegrationTest     : Started ExcelResourceIntegrationTest in 8.519 seconds (JVM running for 11.638)
2020-03-24 04:21:07.638  WARN 4843 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
2020-03-24 04:21:07.642 ERROR 4843 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : (conn:63) Table 'db_test.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist
Query is: select nextval(hibernate_sequence)
```

and this exception into the stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:281)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.springboot.excelapi.service.OrderServiceImpl.insertOrder(OrderServiceImpl.java:27)
    at com.springboot.excelapi.integration.ExcelResourceIntegrationTest.insertOrderServiceTest(ExcelResourceIntegrationTest.java:104)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:40)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStructure$1.getNextValue(SequenceStructure.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:523)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:696)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:554)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn:63) Table 'db_test.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist
Query is: select nextval(hibernate_sequence)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:139)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:101)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.throwAndLogException(ExceptionMapper.java:77)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeQueryEpilog(MariaDbStatement.java:224)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.java:232)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.java:177)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
    ... 93 more
Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: Table 'db_test.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist
Query is: select nextval(hibernate_sequence)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readErrorPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1098)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1030)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:985)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:161)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.java:223)
    ... 97 more
```

Comment: do you have a sequence created for this table in database? If not try this `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is this property, it uses a sequence from table `db_test.hibernate_sequence`.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

if you want to use MySQL incrementing id, please use

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
```

You can tweak Hibernate to create schema on startup in tests, if you need the sequence.